# Django, URL dispatcher not working when using angle brackets to capture a value

Tags: python, django, url, django-rest-framework

core/**settings.py**

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
     ...
    'api.apps.ApiConfig',
     ...
]
```

core/**urls.py** (app URL configuration)

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('api', include("api.urls")),
]
```

api/**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
     path("", views.index, name="API Overview"),
     path("establishment/<str:username>", views.get_id_establishment_auth, name="task-establishment"),
]
```

api/**views.py**

```
@api_view(['GET'])
def get_id_establishment_auth(request, username):
    print(username)
    return HttpResponse('Success');
```

The above code will result a 404 page Page not found if i type http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/establishment/mark when **mark** is a path converter

i cant get what is the problem but looks like the path converter is not working (**str:username**).

Comment: Have you tried it with a trailing slash? `establishment/<str:username>/`

Comment: you are missing a / in api for path('api', include("api.urls")) so should be path('api/', include("api.urls"))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are missing a `/` in api for `path('api', include("api.urls"))` so should be `path('api/', include("api.urls"))`